# c++ pbkdf2 correct results, but do not know how to get into a string from unsigned char

Tags: c++, pbkdf2

I can get the pbkdf2 to work. The output is a BIO_hex_string which contains colons between each char ie "91:BE:23:56:4F:09:FC..." I can also get a std::hex but it only gets one hex char from the output ie "91". I am trying to get a string of all 64 bytes so I can do more things to the string. I am not all that versed in c++ but trying to move to GPU processing so this is a necessity vs my normal language. I know my code is a mess, but I left some of the things I was trying so you might get an idea. Any help appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int iter = 2048;
string myout = "myout";

const char *pass = "password";

unsigned char myString [] = "salt";
unsigned char* salt = &myString[0];

unsigned char myOther [] ="";
unsigned char* out = &myOther[0]; 

unsigned char key[64] = {0};

PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(pass, 8,
    salt, 4,
    iter, EVP_sha512(),
    sizeof(key), key);


std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(*key)); //only gets one    char
std::cout << '\n';

BIO *bio = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

BIO_hex_string(bio,5,sizeof(key),(unsigned char*)key, sizeof(key));
std::cout << '\n';


std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(*key));

BIO_free(bio);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./pbk_example 
91
91:BE:23:56:4F:09:FC:85:5C:82:CE:84:A2:23:EB:E7:D6:3D:8B:49:D6:93:72:59:3A:0D:9E:D3:9E:14:3C:83:E1:AB:2F:72:2A:5D:DB:96:9F:EE:FC:88:40:3F:7E:2A:FE:1A:FB:8B:2F:0E:6B:20:AD:D0:FB:7B:28:36:88:07
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have a string and want to remove the colons from it? Is that correct?

Comment: No, do not yet have a string. The 91:BE... characters are a "BIO_hex_string". I do not know how to convert from the BIO_hex_string to a string that I can work with. The BIO_hex_string goes to the stdout. But I want to do more calculations "91BE2356...."

Answer (score 0):

I have a ways to go with this, but I was able to complete the baby step of getting the entire key to the screen.

```
PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(pass, 8,salt, 4,iter, EVP_sha512(),sizeof(key), key);

ostringstream finalKey;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(key); ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(key[i]);
}

std::cout << '\n';


BIO *bio = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

BIO_hex_string(bio,5,sizeof(key),(unsigned char*)key, sizeof(key));
std::cout << '\n';

BIO_dump(bio,  (const char*)key, sizeof(key));



//std::string s(reinterpret_cast< char const* >(key),63);
//std::cout << std::hex << s << '\n';
//std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<string>(s);
//std::cout << s << '\n';

BIO_free(bio);
```